# UINavigationController pushViewController with xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I have my app, which I haven't used any .xib files to create the UI, until now. I created a ViewController with a xib file, when I push this ViewController. I get 2 navigationbars.

So basically this means... I have been creating my UINavigationController programmatically, and when I put an navigation bar at the top, I get 2 navigation bars.

Somebody can help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more info like why you need to create your uinavigationcontroller programatically AND have an xib? What is the vc hierarchy like? more info would help us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINavigationController adds a navigation bar automatically. If your xib contains another UINavigationBar, there will be two.

Nothing complicated about this :)

Comment: I know, but does this mean I cant resolve it? I need to continue creating my viewcontrollers programmatically?

Comment: No. Just remove UINavigationBar from your xib.

Comment: But I have an UIBarButtonItem on it I want to use :S And I cant take it out if I dont have the UINavigationBar out.

Comment: The data for UINavigationController are read from [UIViewController navigationItem] and this property cannot be set from xib. You have just created a completely different UINavigationBar which is not connected in any way to the UINavigationController. There will always be some things that cannot be done in xib. This is one of them. Set up the navigation bar in the init method of your controller. Everything else can stay in xib.

Comment: If you want, you can hide the navigationbar for the UINavigationController within your pushed viewcontroller in this manner: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`. But, as Sulthan suggested, you could remove your inner navigation bar, keep using the one provided by the UINavigationController. It's more simpler. Within your controller you have full control of your UINavigationController bar. Check this: [UINAvigationController Clas](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)